# "turnjs-magazine" how i replace from image pages to html pages?

Tags: turnjs

i like turnjs-MAGAZINE,

but I need your help for fix:

1- how does to change from IMAGE pages to HTML pages?

code from
http://www.turnjs.com/samples/magazine1/js/magazine1.js

or download: http://www.turnjs.com

Comment: What is the menaing of the two links?

Comment: first link: direct file js, inside there is code of javascript for image. second link download pack of turnjs.

Answer (score 0):

As the Ref Link Indicate : https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/306

we need to perform the following steps

1) Remove following HTML (As re the static reference to pages )

```
<div depth="5" class="hard">
      <div class="side"></div>
</div>

<div depth="5" class="hard front-side">
      <div class="depth"></div>
</div>

<div class="own-size"></div>    
<div class="own-size even"></div>
```

2) remove respective CSS as address in ques

```
.sj-book .p1,
.sj-book .p2,
.sj-book .p3, 
.sj-book .p111, 
.sj-book .p112{
    background-color:white;
    background-image:url(../pics/book-covers.jpg) !important;
}
```

3) copy respective pages to pages folder with the name
Page1.html
Page2.html
and so on..